# Get the current time and compare with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would like to get the current time and compare it with array

Html:

> `<div ng:app ng:controller="Scoper">
>       <p> Now Playing:</p>
>       {{nowPlaying}}
>       <br />
>       <p> Current Time:</p>
>       {{currentTime | date:'HH:mm'}} </div>`

Angular.js:

```
function Scoper($scope) {

  var days = [
    { id: 0 , time:'08:00', channel: 'Gaming'},
    { id: 0 , time:'08:30', channel: 'MUSIC'},
    { id: 0 , time:'09:00', channel: 'Bob the Builder'},
    { id: 0 , time:'09:30', channel: 'Power puff girls'},
    { id: 0 , time:'10:00', channel: 'Spongbob'},
    ];
    /*Get Current time */

     $scope.currentTime = new Date();

    if(days.time === currentTime){
        $scope.nowPlaying= days.channel;
     }
}
```

NB: I know my problem is from when I am comparing the two times, but how do I do it ?

[Sample on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kingleroyg/doqwhssd/1/)

Comment: your Fiddle not even working.

Comment: Scalar value (such as the current time in your code) may be compared with scalar value only. You cannot compare scalar value with `array`. Instead, you have to compare the current time with **each** value of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="Scoper">
    <p> Now Playing:</p>
      {{nowPlaying}}
      <br />
      <p> Current Time:</p>
      {{currentTime | date:'HH:mm'}} 

  </div>
</div>
```

JScript

```
function Scoper($scope) {
  var days = [
    { id: 0 , time:'20:20', channel: 'Gaming'},
    { id: 0 , time:'20:18', channel: 'MUSIC'},
    { id: 0 , time:'20:22', channel: 'Bob the Builder'},
      { id: 0 , time:'20:16', channel: 'Power puff girls'},
    { id: 0 , time:'20:18', channel: 'Spongbob'},
    ];
    /*Get Current time */
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = (currentTime.getMinutes() < 10? '0' : '') + currentTime.getMinutes();
var nowTime = hours + ":" + minutes;

     $scope.currentTime = nowTime;
      for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    if(days[i].time ==  nowTime){
        $scope.nowPlaying= days[i].channel;
        break;    
     }
      else{
       $scope.nowPlaying= "Nothing";
      }
}
}
```

JSFiddle [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/12026/)

Comment: Wow, Thanks, yours was the first one too work + tought me a few extra things, Thanks segar43 :)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you wanr to compare the formatted string and than filter the days array.

This can be done like this:

```
var day = days.filter(
  function(e) { 
    if(e.time === $scope.currentTime.getHours() + ":" + $scope.currentTime.getMinutes()) 
      { return e}; 
    });
if(day.length > 0){
  $scope.eee = day[0].channel;
}
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ow48k6aa/ And it works for me.

But I think what you really want is, getting whether the Current HH:mm is in the Timespan of 08:00 - 08:30, do you?

Than you could do this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gemb36pr/)

```
var day = days.filter(
  function(e) {
    var t = e.time.split(":");
    var minutes = parseInt(t[0])*60 + parseInt(t[1]);
    var currMinutes = $scope.currentTime.getHours() * 60 + $scope.currentTime.getMinutes();   

    if(currMinutes < minutes)           
    { return e}; 
    });
if(day.length > 0){
  $scope.eee = day[0].channel;
}
```

Note! The above only works if the days- array is sorted by Time! Otherwise it needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Another pure JS alternative to parse your time. If you have time saved as 12 hour format you can use en-US or if its a 24 hour format, you can use de-DE.

```
$scope.currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
hour: '2-digit',
minute: '2-digit'
}).replace(/\./g, '/');
```

With this you can use your existing comparision.
You can also expand on this depending on if you want to have the whole date too.
Just use toLocaleDateString.

More about javascript time [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).